# If a meta_key has a meta_value, update the meta_key name

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, mariadb

In a table called `wp_postmeta`, there are ~1K `meta_key`'s called `_wcj_custom_product_tabs_content_local_1`, but only ~100 have a `meta_value`.

What I need to do is update the `meta_key` name, but only for the `meta_key`'s that actually have a `meta_value`.

I can select all the `meta_key`'s that are not empty with this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT meta_value 
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key LIKE '_wcj_custom_product_tabs_content_local_1' 
AND meta_value IS NOT NULL
AND meta_value != ''
```

But then how do I combine the query above with the update query below so only the not empty `meta_key`s selected have their names updated?

```
update wp_postmeta 
set meta_key = 'custom_product_tab_content' 
where meta_key = '_wcj_custom_product_tabs_content_local_1'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the `WHERE` clauses from your `SELECT` query, and prepending the `UPDATE` statement gives you the following query:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
   SET meta_key = 'custom_product_tab_content' 
 WHERE meta_key = '_wcj_custom_product_tabs_content_local_1'
   AND meta_value IS NOT NULL
   AND meta_value != ''
```

Comment: Thanks! That works great. I'm just learning MySQL.